# confusion about the variable of gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT

Tags: webgl

I am learning Webgl currently, in the following example I have a confusing point about the usage of gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT:

```
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#glcanvas");
  // Initialize the GL context
  const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

  // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
  if (!gl) {
    alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.");
    return;
  }
  // Set clear color to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  console.log('1: ', gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Clear the color buffer with specified clear color
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  console.log('2: ', gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

my understanding about `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is setting the value of `gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` to be the color set in `gl.clearColor()`.

So the two `console.log(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` above should output different value. But the real output is as following:

```
1:  16384
2:  16384
```

so what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` is a constant used to tell `clear` what buffer to clear, there's also `DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` and `STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT`, these values are bitmask meaning that you can provide multiple "clear targets" by binary `OR`ing them, e.g. you can clear the color and the depth buffer by calling `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`. Calling `clearColor` sets *the*(there's only one) global clear *color*, there's also `clearDepth` and `clearStencil` functions that set their respective global values.

In other words, `clear` actually clears the given targets using the values that have previously been defined via the `clear****` methods, once set these values persist until you set another value.

Comment: WebGL is certainly not an easy API but bitmasks are a normal part of programming. This is not one of the hard parts of WebGL.